# How to apply remaining width to a div aside sidebar having specific width

Tags: html, css

what I intend to do is following. I have a `div#sidebar` with specific width on the right. This sidebar `div` takes up place on the right. What I now want to do is to apply the remaining width to another `div#left` on the left of sidebar.

But it does not work properly, since the `div`  under the sidebar `div`. I want the `div` to be `100% width` to the margin of sidebar. Not the whole side.
I made an image to explain it better:
 [image: desired output]

Following is the css i currently have:

```
#sidebar {
   height: 100%;
   width: 342px;
   float:right;
}

#left {
   float: left;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
}
```

Hope you get my point. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can absolutely position the `#left` content using `left:0`, `right: width of sidebar` inside a `relative` container. So you'll have better browser support...

HTML

```
<div id='container'>
 <div id='left'></div>
 <div id='sidebar'></div>
</div>
```

css

```
html, body {
 height:100%;
}
#container{
 position:relative; 
 height:100%;
}
#left {
 position:absolute;
 left:0;
 right:342px;
 height: 100%;
}
#sidebar {
 width: 342px;
 height: 100%;
 float:right;
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5BcZs/1/)

Comment: jep thats it, thank you very much! the others worked as well but I want to have 100% browser support!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `calc`. Read [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc) more

So your `#left` div will have width equal to 100% minus the width of the `#sidebar`

```
#sidebar {
   height: 100%;
   width: 342px;
   float:right;
}

#left {
   float: left;
   width: calc(100% - 342px);
   width: -moz-calc(100% - 342px);
   width: -webkit-calc(100% - 342px);
   height: 100%;
}
```

And the [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/KZLJL/4/)

Comment: @supersize not really

Comment: @supersize It is suported from Chrome 19, Firefox 4, IE 9, Safari 6 and beyond

Answer (score 0):

try this code   [DEMO](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/IKjyF)

```
<aside class="panel">
    ...
</aside>
<div class="content">
    ...
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.content {
    overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid;
  height:500px;
}
.panel {
    float: right;
    width: 20%;
  border: 1px solid;
  height:500px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    #sidebar {
       height: 100%;
       width: 342px;
       position:fixed;
       right:0;
       top:0
    }

    #left {
     width:100%;
     box-sizing:border-box;
     padding:0 342px 0 0;
     height: 100%;
    }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vlrprbttst/WYhz4/

Answer (score 0):

Use this Markup

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="sidebar"></div>
    <div class="main"></div>
</div>
```

& CSS:

```
body,html{height:100%;}
.container{display:block; height:100%; padding:0 150px 0 0;}
.container .main{display:block; height:100px; background:#f00;}
.container .sidebar{display:block; float:right; width:150px; height:100%; background:#0f0; margin:0 -150px 0 0;}
```

Here is [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/vJ39H/3/)

Answer (score 0):

Using .calc is probably your easiest option see Demo http://jsfiddle.net/qxEzX/6/

```
<div id="sidebar">Sidebar
</div>
<div id="left">Left 
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#sidebar{height: 100%;  width: 342px; float: right; background: #000000;}
#left{float: left; width: calc(100% - 342px); height: 100% background: #ff0000;}
```